# "No WiFi adapter found" after Ubuntu 18.04 update

Tags: 18.04, wireless

After the latest update (2020/01/17,18), not a clean install, there's "no WIFI adapter found" on my Ubuntu 18.04. The machine is a Win 10 dual boot Lenovo IdeaPad L340. Secure Boot is off (it was before the update, it stayed off after).

Comment: also asked via https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2435241,   also providing details on whether or not you have HWE enabled (ie. kernel & software stack in use) could be very useful. If you boot with an old kernel, is it normal?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure what you're asking though. I did not touch kernel settings at all, the Ubuntu install has been running for about a week. Software is rather minimal, no huge apps in use: a Firefox, LibreOffice, Audacity, music player. Also, don't know what you mean with "booting with an old kernel", never did that.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released using the 4.15 kernel & software stack it was developed with. Upgrades from prior releases, or installs using 18.04 or 18.04.1 media default to that software-stack.  You can however opt to use HWE or hardware enablement stack (which is default for installs with 18.04.2 & later media), the 18.04.2 media used 18.10's software stack, 18.04.3 used 19.04's stack, 18.04.4 uses 19.10's software stack - ie. I was asking which you are using (`uname -r` will tell you the kernel version which is an easy clue).  The other suggestion was to use grub to boot an older kernel..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm using 5.3.0-26 now, by default. This is when the adapter doesn't work. If I load the Ubuntu using the previous one, 5.0.0-37, it works. Also, what changed after the installation of the new Kernel, is that now the Lenovo logo kicks in before loading the Ubuntu anyway. Previously - when it worked fine - it didn't, you could see it only when booting Windows 10.

Comment: Here’s the output: https://ibb.co/k6dBNFy